# Add a getInt24 method to DataView

Tags: javascript, arraybuffer, typed-arrays

I need to extract ints out of an array buffer by putting together 3 bytes. I'm already doing this by using a Uint8Array and doing some bitwise manipulation, but I'm curious to know exactly how typed arrays and dataviews actually convert the raw array buffer data into a type, and whether I can add a getInt24 method to DataView using the same process.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm curious to know exactly how typed arrays and dataviews actually convert the raw array buffer data into a type

- The array needs to know what type of data is being added to it
- The array needs to the size of each slot
- The items you write into the array span multiple bytes
- The byte size ÷ slot size determines the length of the array
- The binary bits stored in each byte occupy a position in memory
- The current position changes after each get/set operation is executed
- The type and order of the data added to the array are needed to read it correctly